# Select only specific columns and display those in gridview control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have generated a mysql query which gives out following output

```
name    club            countryid positionId  description  playersId  DeleteFlag totalClubs
Sidd    qegvwrwrvbwrdb  9     4       dvwrd    17         0           rvwb     


goals   caps    positionName    countryName
1212    12  Angriff     Chile
```

Query :

```
select  
    a.*, p.positionName, c.countryname 
from 
    soccerplayers a  
left join  
    countries c on c.countryId = a.countryId 
left join  
    positions p on p.positionId = a.positionId  
where 
    a.DeleteFlag = 0
```

I only want name, club, description, total clubs, goals, caps, positionName and countryName

C# code

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

MySqlConnection register = new MySqlConnection(cs);
register.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select  a.*,p.positionName,c.countryname from soccerplayers a  left join  countries c on  c.countryId=a.countryId left join  positions p on  p.positionId=a.positionId  where a.DeleteFlag=0", register);

MySqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "soccerplayers");
register.Close();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables["soccerplayers"];

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string name = dr[0].ToString();
    string club = dr[1].ToString();
    string country = dr[11].ToString();
    string position = dr[10].ToString();
    string TotalClubs = dr[7].ToString();
    string description =dr[4].ToString();
    string Goals = dr[8].ToString();
    string caps = dr[9].ToString();

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(name);
    list.Add(club);
    list.Add(country);
    list.Add(position);
    list.Add(TotalClubs);
    list.Add(Goals);
    list.Add(caps);
    list.Add(description);
}

GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: what's the problem that you're having?

Comment: i only want name,club,description,total clubs,goals,caps,positionName and countryName

Comment: it says "A field or property with the name 'name' was not found on the selected data source." Exception

Comment: you should change your query to retrieve only those fields, then assign the datatable as the gridview's datasource

Comment: i tried but this was the best querry i could generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code could completely crap out if you modify the definition for the soccerplayers table because all of those ordinals might change.  You should consider rewriting the query so that it A) Doesn't use select * (**never** use select *); and B) only retrieves the fields you need.

If you rewrite that query, you can just bind the results to the gridview without iterating through the DataTable, assigning variables, creating a list, etc.  When you bind the table, you can chose to set AutoGenerateColumns to true (to make it easier for you) or false (if you need more control over the layout).

Comment: Well i am writing this querry because soccplayers does not contain CountryName and positionName,because on front End CMS i cant countryName and positionId with Numerics

Comment: You can still do a join without the select * by naming the fields you want.  (ie, select a.FirstName, a.LastName... FROM soccerplayer a JOIN...).  In your code you can then do dr["FirstName"] instead of the ordinals which will make is so that your code doesn't break if your table is redefined.

Comment: Thank You Dave Really Appreciate it :)